# Meteor build with settings.json

Tags: meteor

I've build my first Meteor APP with `meteor build ../build`.

But, when i start my app with `node main.js`, i've error because Meteor search information that is in my settings.json, but this information is not find.

Do you know if settings is build ?

Thank you every body,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Populate environment variable

```
export METEOR_SETTINGS="$(cat /path/to/settings.json )"
```

after the build step and before you execute your code

To confirm your json is valid issue

```
echo "$METEOR_SETTINGS" | jq .
```

which uses the [command line utility jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

here is a redacted content of env var METEOR_SETTINGS ( same as /path/to/settings.json )

```
echo $METEOR_SETTINGS | jq .

{
  "public": {
    "rootUrl": "https://example.com",
    "secure": true,
    "minSearchChars": 2,
    "supportEmail": "support@coolstartup.com",
    "fromUser": "support@example.com",
    "GcmSender": 8577956,
    "maxBodySize": 15,
    "cordovaHost": "http://localhost:12416",
    "failedAuthsLimit": 5
  },
  "environ": {
    "enduserUrl": "https://example.com",
    "adminUrl": "https://admin.example.com",
    "scanUrl": "example.com:3310",
    "scanTries": 4,
    "opsCheckToken": "foobaroJ1b3UOi",
    "bootstrapUser": {
      "name": "Server Daemon",
      "email": "daemon@coolstartup.com",
      "password": "123123"
    },
    "pollingTries": 5,
    "expireResetToken": 1,
    "expireEnrollToken": 8,
    "fromUser": "support@example.com",
    "replyTo": "support@coolstartup.com"
  },
  "notifs": {
    "apn": {
      "expiry": 1123200,
      "production": false,
      "appName": "app"
    },
    "gcm": {
      "timeToLive": 1123200
    }
  },
  "vidyoyoyoyo": {
    "key": "f6acfc0ea9d ",
    "appID": "d06eec.o.io",
    "userName": "foo@bar.com",
    "expiresInSeconds": 10000
  },
  "logLevel": 4,
  "jsonSpaces": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the flag `--mobile-settings=settings.json` when running your build:

`meteor build /apr/myAppp --server=https://myApp.herokuapp.com --mobile-settings=settings.json`